# Cancel common factors from two polynomials without merging them into a ration function expression

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, fractions

I'd like to cancel a rational function `f1(z)=p1(z)/q1(z)` given by two polynomial expressions `p1,q1`.

An almost complete solution would be the following

```
import sympy as sp
z = sp.symbols('z')
p1 = z**2 - 1
q1 = z**2 - z
f1 = p1/q1
f2 = f1.cancel() # -> (z + 1)/z
```

where the missing step would be to extract the `q2,p2` from `f2` (which I don't know how to accomplish).

However, **this is not my preferred approach** as all my code is based on the `p,q`, the above approach seems like like an unneccesary roundtrip `p1,q1 -> f1 -> f2 -> p2,q1` over the function representation `f` which I'd like to avoid due to performance risks and simplicity.

Instead I'd like to directly compute them `q1, p1 -> q2,p2`, i.e., **I seek a solution of this form**

```
cancel_common(p1, q1) # -> z+1, z
```

I expect that this functionality should exist, or should be simple to implement with provided manipulation features, because the `q,p` provide a much more explicit input to the problem, than `p/q`.

I thought a starting point could be `sympy.Rational` because it is explicitly based on the numerator-denominator-representation, but it unfortunately cannot handle the symbol `z` (i.e. does not work with functions):

```
sp.Rational(p1, q1) # -> TypeError: invalid input: z**2 - 1
```

Does anyone know a way how to accomplish this?

Comment: OK, I just found that `_, p2, q2 = sp.polys.cofactors(p1, q1)` might be exactly what I need :)

Comment: For performance it would be better to work with `Poly` always in this kind of calculation: `Poly(z**2 - 1, z).cofactors(Poly(z**2 - z, z))` because otherwise a function like `cofactors` has to convert an ordinary SymPy `Expr` to `Poly` and back each time.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin I don't fully understand your argument, don't the two `Poly(...)` in your example code also convert expressions to `Poly`?

Comment: The idea is to construct Poly at the start of your program and then perform only operations with Poly throughout. Otherwise every polynomial function like `cofactors`, `factor`, `gcd` etc will convert back and forth on each call.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Thanks, I see. Changing my whole program datatype *globally* is not an option (as the program is more complex than my above example sketch). So from these constraints my only option is to *locally* wrap a conversion to `Poly` around *one* call of `cofactors`. I'd think that this would only improve performance, if even *one* call of `cofactors` performs multiple conversions in an algorithmic fashion (e.g. growing with the polynomial order), did You also want to say the latter is the case and wrapping `Poly` conversion around single `cofactors` calls would still pay off?

Comment: If you are only using a single call to `cofactors` then there is little performance gain in doing the conversion explicitly. It is still a little more efficient if you can specify exactly how to convert to poly e.g. by specifying the domain and generators rather than requiring `Poly` to have to detect that itself.